# Alternative for Static Field

Tags: c#, static

Is there any alternative present for Static Field in C# as static field never garbage collected?
If I want to declaure the number of strings, constants which I want to use throughout the program, I am finding a way for that.

Comment: You can use constant for that, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6w8fe1b.aspx

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking.  Perhaps you want to use a `const`?

Comment: common class with public variables/constants/strings can be used for this.

Comment: If you'll set a static field to null... The object previously stored in the static field **will** get garbage collected (also assuming no other reference). Not sure if that addresses your concern, or you still have something else in mind. If you would clarify further on your question.

Comment: well why would you want the GC to clean away stuff you "want to use thrroughout the program" anyway?

Comment: Well, you could perhaps think of a separate struct with properties set to certain values. A default constructor would initialize such properties. Struct is different from class in the sense that it is placed on stack and is removed when programs leaves scope.

Comment: What is the problem you're trying to solve here?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `const` but it has to be a `value`.

```
public class Foo 
{
   public const string Bar = "Bar";
}
```

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6w8fe1b.aspx

Comment: Richard, the links is broken. MSDN says "We're sorry, the page you requested cannot be found."

Answer (score 2):

As an addition to *Richard Schneiders* answer, sometimes you can't use `const` (the compiler should know the const value at the compiling time), but want to provide *constant like behaviou*r. In that case `readonly` is the choice:

```
  public class Foo {
    // Settings should be read and then preserved intact
    public static readonly String Settings = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\MySettings.txt");
    ...
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can Use `Const` for this.

Const is a reserved word. It allows us to specify that a value is invariant and must not be modified after compile-time. Const values, like const strings, help us simplify and optimize programs.

Eg:

```
public static class Constants
{
    public const string Name = "abc";
}
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acdd6hb7.aspx